# Javascript Objects and the DOM

Tags: javascript, html, dom, object

So we all know you can create JavaScript objects quite simply as:

```
var myObject = new Object() ;
myObject.attribute = someValue ;
myObject.doSomething = someFunction ;
```

We can then use that object within JavaScript to manipulate the DOM using the standard techniques one would except eg:

```
document.getEmelemntByID("some ID").someAttribute = myObject.attribute;
```

Now this is simply using the facilities of JavaScript to query the DOM to find some element and then set an attribute, all well and good.  You can do the same thing with jQuery and other tools, all of which are based on JavaScript.

One can call a JavaScript function with any of the various methods the DOM provides such as onClick, onChange, etc. etc.

So my question is how does one actually have a JavaScript object IN the dom, with say a draw method a click method, etc. etc.  This would allow DOM to execute the draw method to render something on the DOM canvas and then call a method particular to that object on say click or double click?

Answer (score 1):

You can't make your own types of objects in the DOM and create new browser level events with javascript.  You must create one of the types of objects that the browser DOM already supports and use the events that those objects support.  It is possible to use native code to create browser plug-ins (like Adobe Flash) that will do some of what you're asking, but I don't think that's what you wanted as those aren't implemented in javascript and require downloads.

You can however use a generic object like a `<div>` and respond to click events on it in any way you want.   Since a div has no default behavior for clicks and drawing, it's just a placeholder in the DOM.  You can then embed your own objects inside of it or set properties on it to create whatever visual look you want.  And, you can handle the various events on it (clicks, keys, etc...) to give it the desired behavior.  So, you can think of a generic object like a `<div>` as scaffolding which you can build your own object look and behavior on.

There are even ways to put a javascript wrapper around the DOM object so most of your interaction with that object appears to be with your javascript object instead of with the actual DOM object (that's what both jQuery and YUI do).  But, underneath, it's still a real DOM object with your own javascript wrapper around it.

Answer (score 1):

The DOM tree is made up of Javascript objects, specifically different kinds of element objects. You can't put other objects in the DOM tree.

The DOM elements uses events for customisable actions, not methods. The click event for example is activated when someone clicks on the element. You hook up a method as event handler for an event, and that method will be called when the event is activated.